# How to get first-level children of an element in jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

In jsoup `Element.children()` returns all children (descendants) of Element. But, I want the Element's first-level children (direct children).

Which method can I use?

Comment: `Element.children()` returns direct children, is not it? If you are in doubt, try `Element.children().size()`.

Comment: I tried this. It returns all children (children and children of children).

Comment: How are you trying it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Element.children() returns direct children only. Since you get them bound to a tree, they have children too.

If you need the direct children elements without the underlying tree structure then you need to create them as follows

```
public static void main(String... args) {

    Document document = Jsoup
            .parse("<div><ul><li>11</li><li>22</li></ul><p>ppp<span>sp</span</p></div>");

    Element div = document.select("div").first();
    Elements divChildren = div.children();

    Elements detachedDivChildren = new Elements();
    for (Element elem : divChildren) {
        Element detachedChild = new Element(Tag.valueOf(elem.tagName()),
                elem.baseUri(), elem.attributes().clone());
        detachedDivChildren.add(detachedChild);
    }

    System.out.println(divChildren.size());
    for (Element elem : divChildren) {
        System.out.println(elem.tagName());
    }

    System.out.println("\ndivChildren content: \n" + divChildren);

    System.out.println("\ndetachedDivChildren content: \n"
            + detachedDivChildren);
}
```

Output

```
2
ul
p

divChildren content: 
<ul>
 <li>11</li>
 <li>22</li>
</ul>
<p>ppp<span>sp</span></p>

detachedDivChildren content: 
<ul></ul>
<p></p>
```

Comment: Inside the loop it can also be done cleaner way like this.
for (Element elem : divChildren) {
elem = elem.clone();
elem.empty();
detachedDivChildren.add(detachedChild);
    }

Answer (score 3):

This should give you the desired list of direct descendants of the parent node:

```
Elements firstLevelChildElements = doc.select("parent-tag > *");
```

OR You can also try to retrieve the parent element, get the first child node via `child(int index)` and then try to retrieve siblings of this child via `siblingElements()`.

This will give you the list of first level children excluding the used child, however you'd have to add the child externally.

```
Elements firstLevelChildElements = doc.child(0).siblingElements();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always use the ELEMENT.child(index) with the index you can choose which child you want.

Comment: Thanks. It is useful when you know which child you look for. In the algorithm I am implementing, I don't know.

Comment: Couldnt you just give them and predifned index for example in the class and use that index to get them?

Comment: The life should be easier than it. Returning the first-level children of an element is a very basic method almost all parsers support. The problem with indexing is that I don't know how many direct-children the ELEMENT has. In addition, seems indexing is done from leaves to parents, and makes it difficult to use them.

Comment: hmmm I see you could always get all the element with the first method and by guessing that the first element is the direct children you could always put it in a table or something and get only the first one

Comment: Find it finally: parent > child: child elements that descend directly from parent, e.g. div.content > p finds p elements; and body > * finds the direct children of the body tag.

Comment: It doesn't work. On the website it says that select (">*") returns the direct children, but I checked it, and it returns all children.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can get the value of first-level children

```
 Element addDetails = doc.select("div.container > div.main-content > div.clearfix > div.col_7.post-info > ul.no-bullet").first();
    Elements divChildren = addDetails.children();
    for (Element elem : divChildren) {
       System.out.println(elem.text());
                }
```