# select tr from a table in JSOUP

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I want to get the TR tags from a table as Elements as I explained. But when I am using

```
Elements elementObj = doc.select("table").select("tr");
```

It is getting all the TR tags present in the table. But I want just the parent TR tags as Element that I highlighted, Not the child TR tags. Anyone help me please!

```
<table>
   <tr>//This tr as Element
      <td>
         <table>
             <tr>
                !!!NOT these tr
             </tr>
         </table>
      </td>
   </tr>           
   <tr>//This tr as Element
      <td>
         <table>
             <tr>
                !!!NOT these tr
             </tr>
         </table>
      </td> 
   </tr>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060853/how-to-get-first-level-children-of-an-element-in-jsoup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue using the following code :

```
Elements elementobj = doc.select("table>tr");
```

This gets the first level children.

Answer (score 1):

Use `children()`, it gives you only direct nodes. So use it like this:

```
Elements elementObj = doc.select("table").first().children().select("tr");
```

This is assuming you have only one `table` element, if there are many, you should first get all `table` elements, then iterate through them and call `children()` on each of them.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thank you.