# How to get only n-level elements with Jsoup?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I have a huge table of content which have multiple layers:

[image]

I need to edit it and keep only elements of `Level1` and `Level2` and remove everything else, as:

[image]

For this reason I use Jsoup:

```
File in = new File(INPUT_FILE_PATH);
Document origDoc = Jsoup.parse(in, null);
Elements toc = origDoc.getElementsByClass("toc");
Elements firstLevelChildElements = toc.select("ul");
```

Then I thought to analyze elements, if the element has only one parent - keep it, otherwise remove it.

But the problem is that `firstLevelChildElements` selects the first `ul` and all its children. The same happens when I try to select the nexts child element. I cannot have just a list (or tree) of all my elements.

The example HTML code is:

```
<ul class="toc">
    <li>
        <a href="#toc_20">Level 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#toc_21">Level 2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#toc_22">Level 3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#toc_28">Level 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#toc_29">Level 2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#toc_20">Level 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#toc_21">Level 2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#toc_22">Level 3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16060853/how-to-get-first-level-children-of-an-element-in-jsoup) is nice, but unfortunately doesn't work for me.

Comment: Your example is the input. Can you show us exactly what output you would like to be able to produce from this input? The way I see it, level 1 is two list items, and level 2 is four list items. Are you able to modify the HTML such that you add `<li class="level2">`? This would simplify the Jsoup selectors.

Comment: @ThisClark thank you for comment, I updated the question. The problem is that all the `li`s and `ul`s don't have classes.

Comment: Ok, I understand the output you are expecting is the modified HTML appearing exactly as your second screenshot. Is that correct?

Comment: I think this is my last question - since you wrote in Java, what data type do you want to get at the end? Do you want a `String` of HTML, a Jsoup `Document` of modified HTML or a collection of `Elements`?

Comment: @ThisClark This is correct, I expect the modified HTML, as represented on the second picture. And I would like to get `String` of HTML, because further I would like to replace the table of content with new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Jsoup you can manipulate dom. Select all elements you do not want and empty their html. You can use css selectors to do this:

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    for (Element e : doc.select("ul > li > ul > li > ul")) {
        e.html("");
    }
```

or more generaly to select all fourth order children of ul element with toc class:

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    for (Element e : doc.select("ul.toc > * > * > * > * > *")) {
        e.html("");
    }
```

Then select required elements from modified document.

More about css selectors:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

Comment: Thank you for response, but with this approach I got just empty String `<li></li><li></li><ul></ul><li></li>`.

Comment: I have tested this on the sample html you have provided. If your actual html is different you will need to adapt the code.

Comment: I use the same HTML snippet, I put the `System.out.println(e);` in the loop, and got only that empty tags.

Comment: Add System.out.println(doc) after the loop

Comment: In the loop you make tags that are Level 3 and more empty. After the loop you have html without this tags, i.e. only level 1 and level 2